# excel, check if string contains a character a-z or A-Z

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column with unstructured data. I need to detect if the string has an alphabetical character meaning a-z or A-Z. I am not sure how to do this in excel with a formula or other. I am thinking this could be a long countif and sumproduct. Or maybe regex in excel. I will post an attempt try once I try this out more. But I am looking for some advice. While searching online, I could not find a formula to do this. Thanks for your help. Please see below screenshot for sample data.

[image]

Comment: regex using pattern `[a-zA-Z]`

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you run into problems? What version of Excel do you have?

Answer (score 5):

Using the fact that `a` to `z` is `99` to `122` in ASCII, you can use `SEARCH`, which is case-insensitive:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CHAR(ROW($99:$122)),A2)))>0,"Yes","No")
```

**Note** that inserting or deleting rows will change the `$99:$122` so only use this approach if you can ensure that it remains unchanged.

Comment: I've been around Excel for a long time and I've never seen anyone use "--".  I had to google it to find out what it does and that's pretty stinking cool.  For those who haven't seen it: "--" converts the boolean True/False to 1/0.  I'll upvote this just for that bit of new information.

Comment: @FrankBall - yes, the [double unary](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary)... Check out Scott Craner's answers - it's used all the time. Neat little trick.

Comment: @BigBen I would caution against using `ROW(...` to generate a list of numbers. The row numbers will get changed if you fill-down the formula.  And will get altered, even if you use absolute addressing, if you insert a row within the range where you have the formula.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - yeah the absolute is a good point... that is a good caveat. I like your SEQUENCE approach.

Comment: @BigBen But even absolute addressing won't eliminate the issue of inserted rows changing the range.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yes, I agree... I meant "that is a good caveat" as a point to OP - caution when using this approach, only use if you remember that 99 to 122 should not change.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `SEARCH` is case-insensitive, so you can use:

```
    =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J";"K";"L";"M";"N";"O";"P";"Q";"R";"S";"T";"U";"V";"W";"X";"Y";"Z"},A8))),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

If you have a later version of O365 with the `SEQUENCE` function, you can use:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CHAR(SEQUENCE(26,,65,1)),A1))),"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not case sensitive so it will return `Yes` for `a|A`

---

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("A$1:A"&LEN(A1))),1),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"))),"Yes","No")
```